# How to re-raise the same exception without the traceback?

Tags: python, exception, traceback, backtrace

In an `except` block I want to raise the same exception but *without* the stack trace and *without* the information that this exception has been raised as direct cause of another exception. (and without modifying `sys.tracebacklimit` globally)

Additionally I have a very clumsy exception class which parses and modifies the message text so I can't just reproduce it.

My current approach is

```
try:
    deeply_nested_function_that_raises_exception()
except ClumsyExceptionBaseClass as exc:
    cls, code, msg = exc.__class__, exc.code, exc.msg
raise cls("Error: %d %s" % (code, msg))
```

What I'm doing here is **de-composing** the exception information, **re-assemble** a new exception with a message which will be parsed and split into error code and message in the constructor and raise it **from outside the `except` block** in order to forget all trace information.

Is there a more pythonic way to do this? All I want is get rid of the noisy (and useless in my case) trace back while keeping the information contained in the exception object..

Comment: It sounds like you want to change the representation of the exception and not the exception itself.

Comment: The most pythonic thing to do here is to leave the original exception and traceback alone. As far as I'm concerned I just positively HATE it when someone think he's smart enough to know which parts of the original exception / original traceback are going to be useful to ME. It just happens that I have this exact issue right now with some inept exception handler in reportlab that prevents me from getting needed infos to fix a critical bug on our product, and I'll have to actually fork the whole project and deploy this fork on production just to get the original exception and full traceback.

Comment: I don't want to change exception representation in general but in a few cases where it's very clear that just the local context is needed to find the problem (e.g. a `get(<name>)` function with a deeply nested lookup resulting in a very obvious `KeyError`. In `pytest` scenarios with thousands of tests you sometimes have hundreds of megabytes of useless stack trace with 99% repeated information which make it very hard to find the _actual_ problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3, you can use `with_traceback` to remove the traceback entries accumulated so far:

```
try: ...
except Exception as e:
  raise e.with_traceback(None)
```

In Python 2, it’s just

```
try: ...
except Exception as e:
  raise e   # not just "raise"
```

It will of course still show the trace to *this* line, since that’s added as the exception propagates (again).